# Nightwatchjs - Verify if checkbox is ticked, always return value false even if its already ticked

Tags: javascript, automation, nightwatch.js

I'm currently doing a test to verify if the checkbox is selected, tick it if found the checkbox status is false. I have already able to mark the checkbox if found unchecked. The problem is that when I check the status of the checkbox that is already ticked, it always return 'FALSE'.

Can anyone help me verify my code? Thanks!

Here is my code:

checkbox.js

```
Given(/^the sysadmin activates a system product/, () => {
    client.element('class name', 'checkmark', function(response) {
        client.assert.ok(response.value.ELEMENT, 'Checkbox response OK');
        client.elementIdSelected(response.value.ELEMENT, function(result){
            console.log("Status: ", result);
            console.log("Status: ", result.value);
            if (result.value == false) {
                console.log("Result value is ", result.value);
                SYSPRODUCTSOBJ.click('@sysProductBlood')
                .waitForElementVisible('@sysProductSaveBtn', 6000)
                .click('@sysProductSaveBtn');
            }
            client.verify.ok(result.value, 'Checkbox selected');
        });
    });
    return client.pause(2000);
});
```

elementModel.js

```
    module.exports = {
    elements: {
        sysProductBlood: {
            selector: ".//*[@data-v-594c377e]//*[@for='1']//*[@class='checkmark']",
            locateStrategy: 'xpath'
        },
        sysProductSaveBtn: {
            selector: ".//*[@class='system-product']//*[@class='btn btn-default']",
            locateStrategy: 'xpath'
        },
}
```

HTML

```
<label data-v-594c377e="" for="1"><input data-v-594c377e="" type="checkbox" id="1" value="BloodControl"><div data-v-594c377e="" class="checkmark"></div>BloodControl</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things where things become weirdly inconsistent. I've been bitten by this one before too.

Checkboxes use the `checked` property, not `value`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. On the page, when I click the checkbox, no attribute or property 'checked' is being displayed when checked on the console. How can I get a workaround for that?